# Excel: Subtract 2 values based on multiple criteria to get message response rate

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

Hi I'm trying to track the response rates in various message threads and am having trouble writing the formula. I included a link to a sample data set as well as the sudo formula below. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Data Set Link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tgocXxXtLNtIzsDQYVGleSpfjzDi73y61CFZCsKRGvM/edit?usp=sharing

Sudo Formula:

If ("Actionable" = "Y")

Then find the next row that has:

a) the next "Message #" in the sequence
AND
b) the same "thread_id"
AND
c) Sent by Other User = "N"

Then subtract the "Date" value of the second row from the first row

Data Set:

> user_id   thread_id   message_id  date    fromUser_id Sent by Other User  Message #   Actionable  ResponseTime
>
> 3198  5555    22115   1/22/2016 20:41:00  1109    Y   1   Y
> 3198  5555    22217   1/25/2016 4:22:00   3198    N   2   N
> 3198  5555    22225   1/25/2016 15:03:00  1109    Y   3   Y
> 3198  5555    22226   1/25/2016 15:04:00  1109    Y   4   N
> 3198  5555    22228   1/25/2016 17:01:00  3198    N   5   N
> 3198  5555    22229   1/25/2016 17:03:00  1109    Y   6   N
> 3198  5555    22230   1/25/2016 17:04:00  3198    N   7   N
> 3198  5555    22245   1/25/2016 22:27:00  3198    N   8   N
> 3198  5555    22246   1/25/2016 22:36:00  1109    Y   9   N
> 3198  5555    22247   1/25/2016 22:37:00  3198    N   10  N
> 3198  5723    22860   2/2/2016 1:45:00    3001    Y   1   Y
> 3198  5723    22861   2/2/2016 1:47:00    3198    N   2   N
> 3198  5723    22863   2/2/2016 1:48:00    3001    Y   3   N
> 3198  5723    22864   2/2/2016 1:51:00    3198    N   4   N
> 3198  5723    22869   2/2/2016 1:56:00    3001    Y   5   N
> 3198  5723    22876   2/2/2016 2:01:00    3198    N   6   N
> 3198  5723    22879   2/2/2016 2:03:00    3001    Y   7   N
> 3198  5723    22880   2/2/2016 2:04:00    3198    N   8   N
> 3198  5723    22946   2/2/2016 19:23:00   3001    Y   9   N
> 3198  5723    22947   2/2/2016 19:26:00   3198    N   10  N
> 3198  5723    22948   2/2/2016 19:26:00   3001    Y   11  N
> 3198  5723    22949   2/2/2016 19:27:00   3198    N   12  N
> 3198  5723    22950   2/2/2016 19:27:00   3001    Y   13  N
> 3198  5723    22951   2/2/2016 19:28:00   3198    N   14  N
> 3198  5723    22975   2/2/2016 20:57:00   3198    N   15  N
> 3198  5723    22977   2/2/2016 20:58:00   3001    Y   16  N
> 3198  5723    22978   2/2/2016 20:58:00   3001    Y   17  N
> 3198  5723    22979   2/2/2016 20:58:00   3198    N   18  N
> 3198  5723    22980   2/2/2016 20:59:00   3001    Y   19  N
> 3198  5723    22981   2/2/2016 21:00:00   3198    N   20  N
> 3198  5723    22982   2/2/2016 21:00:00   3198    N   21  N
> 3198  5723    22983   2/2/2016 21:00:00   3198    N   22  N
> 3198  5723    22984   2/2/2016 21:00:00   3001    Y   23  N
> 3198  5764    23019   2/3/2016 3:08:00    358     Y   1   Y
> 3198  5764    23020   2/3/2016 3:09:00    3198    N   2   N
> 3198  5764    23022   2/3/2016 3:12:00    358     Y   3   N
> 3198  5764    23023   2/3/2016 3:19:00    3198    N   4   N
> 3198  5764    23125   2/3/2016 20:20:00   3198    N   5   N
> 3198  5764    23126   2/3/2016 20:26:00    358    Y   6   N
> 3198  6188    24668   2/16/2016 23:45:00  2983    Y   1   Y
> 3198  6188    24693   2/17/2016 2:30:00   3198    N   2   N
> 3198  6188    24695   2/17/2016 2:43:00   2983    Y   3   N
> 3198  6188    24696   2/17/2016 2:43:00   2983    Y   4   N
> 3198  6188    24698   2/17/2016 2:44:00   3198    N   5   N
> 3198  6188    24699   2/17/2016 2:44:00   3198    N   6   N
> 3198  6188    24700   2/17/2016 2:45:00   2983    Y   7   N
> 3198  6188    24708   2/17/2016 3:15:00   3198    N   8   N
> 3198  6188    24710   2/17/2016 3:18:00   2983    Y   9   N
> 3198  6188    24784   2/17/2016 20:33:00  3198    N   10  N
> 3198  7035    28025   3/21/2016 19:59:00  3579    Y   1   Y
> 3198  7035    28068   3/21/2016 22:16:00  3198    N   2   N
> 3198  7035    28070   3/21/2016 22:17:00  3579    Y   3   N
> 3198  7035    28119   3/22/2016 2:17:00   3198    N   4   N
> 3198  7035    28120   3/22/2016 2:18:00   3198    N   5   N
> 3198  7035    28167   3/22/2016 15:07:00  3579    Y   6   N
> 3198  7035    28187   3/22/2016 17:06:00  3198    N   7   N
> 3198  7035    28236   3/22/2016 20:42:00  3579    Y   8   N
> 3198  7035    28254   3/22/2016 21:43:00  3198    N   9   N
> 3198  7035    28356   3/23/2016 13:43:00  3198    N   10  N
> 3198  7035    28357   3/23/2016 13:43:00  3198    N   11  N
> 3198  7035    28375   3/23/2016 15:36:00  3579    Y   12  N
> 3198  7035    28380   3/23/2016 16:05:00  3198    N   13  N
> 3198  7035    28392   3/23/2016 18:10:00  3579    Y   14  N
> 3198  7035    28399   3/23/2016 19:04:00  3198    N   15  N
> 3198  7035    28400   3/23/2016 19:05:00  3198    N   16  N
> 3198  7035    28406   3/23/2016 19:17:00  3579    Y   17  N
> 3198  7035    28436   3/23/2016 20:03:00  3579    Y   18  N

Comment: Why don't you put that into code?

Comment: I don't how to write code, I was looking for an excel formula that could make the calculations

Comment: Show some data please it will help.

Comment: I included a link to a google doc with the data, let me know if you have trouble accessing

Comment: No one is going to click on a random link. Scott is asking you to post data into your question.

Comment: Pasted data to the question, not sure if there's a cleaner way to add it

Answer (score 2):

In I2:J2 as standard formulas.

```
'in I2 with hours as integers with decimals as a base10 decimal of an hour
'with 0.00\h\r\s as cell formatting
=IF(H2="Y", (AGGREGATE(15, 6, D3:D999/((B3:B999=B2)*(F3:F999="N")*(G3:G999>G2)), 1)-D2)*24, TEXT(,))
'in J2 as true time
'with [hh]:mm as cell formatting
=IF(H2="Y", AGGREGATE(15, 6, D3:D999/((B3:B999=B2)*(F3:F999="N")*(G3:G999>G2)), 1)-D2, TEXT(,))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: response_time]

Comment: @Jeeped this looks correct, thanks so much! The only thing I've found is that when there is no response it gives a "#NUM!" instead of saying "No Response." However that use case is not covered in the data set I gave. Would you mind including that in the formula as well?

Comment: As an [enthusiast programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) I'm sure you will be able to find the 'best practise' for [dealing with potential errors](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb#__toc309306713) in an Excel formula.